# three js hole is not rendered in a shape

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a simple parametrized shape (rectangular) with a hole in a middle to create a frame. Sadly a hole isn't created. Console says `THREE.ShapeUtils: Infinite Loop! Holes left:" + indepHoles.length + ", Probably Hole outside Shape!` But after debugging session I find it wrong. This is my code with comments that include the x,y coordinates of `.currentpoint`

```
    var frameblock = new THREE.Shape();
frameblock.moveTo(topleft.x - 2*99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 2*99/Math.SQRT2); // move to topleft x: -570 y: 410
frameblock.lineTo(topright.x + 99/Math.SQRT2,topright.y + 2*99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topright x: 1092 y: 410
frameblock.lineTo(bottomright.x + 2* 99/Math.SQRT2  ,bottomright.y - 99/Math.SQRT2 ); //draw to bottomright x: 1092 y: -570
frameblock.lineTo(topleft.x - 2*99/Math.SQRT2,bottomleft.y - 99/Math.SQRT2); //draw to bottomleft x: -570 y:-570
frameblock.lineTo(topleft.x - 2*99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 2*99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topleft x: -570 y: 410

var framehole = new THREE.Path();
framehole.moveTo(topleft.x - 99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 99/Math.SQRT2); // move to topleft x: -500 y: 340
framehole.lineTo(topright.x,topright.y + 99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topright x:1022 y:340
framehole.lineTo(bottomright.x + 99/Math.SQRT2  ,bottomright.y); //draw to bottomright x:1022 y:-500
framehole.lineTo(topleft.x - 99/Math.SQRT2,bottomleft.y); //draw to bottomleft x: -500 y: -500
framehole.lineTo(topleft.x - 99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topleft x: -500 y: 340

frameblock.holes.push(framehole);

var framegeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(frameblock);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was it was not drawn counterclockwise. So the right order is:

```
 var frameblock = new THREE.Shape();
frameblock.moveTo(topleft.x - 2*99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 2*99/Math.SQRT2); // move to topleft x: -570 y: 410
frameblock.lineTo(topleft.x - 2*99/Math.SQRT2,bottomleft.y - 99/Math.SQRT2); //draw to bottomleft x: -570 y:-570
frameblock.lineTo(bottomright.x + 2* 99/Math.SQRT2  ,bottomright.y - 99/Math.SQRT2 ); //draw to bottomright x: 1092 y: -570
frameblock.lineTo(topright.x + 99/Math.SQRT2,topright.y + 2*99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topright x: 1092 y: 410
frameblock.lineTo(topleft.x - 2*99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 2*99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topleft x: -570 y: 410

var framehole = new THREE.Path();
framehole.moveTo(topleft.x - 99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 99/Math.SQRT2); // move to topleft x: -500 y: 340
framehole.lineTo(topleft.x - 99/Math.SQRT2,bottomleft.y); //draw to bottomleft x: -500 y: -500
framehole.lineTo(bottomright.x + 99/Math.SQRT2  ,bottomright.y); //draw to bottomright x:1022 y:-500
framehole.lineTo(topright.x,topright.y + 99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topright x:1022 y:340
framehole.lineTo(topleft.x - 99/Math.SQRT2,topleft.y + 99/Math.SQRT2); // draw to topleft x: -500 y: 340



frameblock.holes.push(framehole);
```